# Entire JS code executes when addEventListener is called on click button

Tags: javascript

On clicking the adminBtn the catview and listview render as mentioned in the addEventListener method. But post this, the entire js code executes again, model ,listview ,catview, adminform, modelsetter are set again, and adminform.init() is also called.I don't know why this is happening.Below is my app.js file. Please assist.

```
var adminBtn = document.getElementById('admin-form');

var model = {
    currentCat : null,
    cats : [{name: "Ait",
   imgsrc: "image.jpg",
   count: 0},
  {name: "Bop",
   imgsrc: "image1.jpg",
   count: 0},
  {name: "Cal",
   imgsrc: "image2.jpg",
   count: 0},
  {name: "Don",
   imgsrc: "image3.jpg",
   count: 0},
  {name: "Ema",
   imgsrc: "image4.jpg",
   count: 0}]
};

  var listview = {
        init : function(){
              this.nav = document.getElementById('list');
              this.render();
        },
        render : function(){
              while(this.nav.firstChild){
                    this.nav.removeChild(this.nav.firstChild);
              }
              for(var i = 0 ; i < model.cats.length ; i++){
                    var catElement = document.createElement('li');
                    catElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(model.cats[i].name));
                    this.nav.appendChild(catElement);
                    catElement.addEventListener('click', (function(cat) {
                          return function() {
                                modelsetter.setCurrentCat(cat);
                                catview.render();
                          };
                          })(model.cats[i]));
              }
        },
  };

  var catview = {
        init : function(){
              this.catName = document.getElementById('cat-name');
              this.catCount = document.getElementById('cat-clicks');
              this.catImage = document.getElementById('cat-image');
              this.catImage.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    modelsetter.incrementCount();
              });
              this.render();
        },
        render : function(){
              var currentCat = modelsetter.getCurrentCat();
              this.catImage.setAttribute('src', currentCat.imgsrc);
              this.catCount.innerHTML = currentCat.count;
              this.catName.innerHTML = currentCat.name;
        }
  };

  var adminform = {
        init : function(){
              adminBtn.addEventListener('submit', function(){
                    this.catName = document.getElementById('new-cat-name').value;
                    this.catCount = document.getElementById('new-cat-count').value;
                    this.catImage = document.getElementById('new-cat-image').value;
                    var currentCat = modelsetter.getCurrentCat();
                    modelsetter.updateCat(currentCaamot);      
                    listview.render();
                    catview.render();
              });
        }
  };

  var modelsetter = {
        init : function(){
              model.currentCat = this.getCurrentCat() || model.cats[0];
              listview.init();
              catview.init();
        },
        getCurrentCat : function(){
              return model.currentCat;
        },
        setCurrentCat : function(cat){
              model.currentCat = cat;
        },
        incrementCount : function(){
              model.currentCat.count++;
              catview.render();
        },
        updateCat : function(cat){
              this.catName = adminBtn.catName;
              this.catCount = adminBtn.catCount;
              this.catImage = adminBtn.catImage;
              for(var i = 0 ; i < model.cats.length ; i++){
                    if(cat.name === model.cats[i].name){
                          model.cats[i].name = this.catName;
                          model.cats[i].imgsrc = this.catImage;
                          model.cats[i].count = this.catCount;
                    }
              }
        }
  };

  modelsetter.init();
  adminform.init();
```

Comment: form submit results in new page being laoded ... try `adminBtn.addEventListener('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ... rest of your code...`

Answer (score 1):

As Jaromanda mentioned in the comments, you want to change

```
...
adminBtn.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    this.catName = document.getElementById('new-cat-name').value;
...
```

to

```
...
adminBtn.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.catName = document.getElementById('new-cat-name').value;
...
```

That `e.preventDefault()` should prevent the `submit` event from actually submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks Garrett and Jaromanda for your insights :). Got it to work with your help.